# Iterating and averaging pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database with a lot of rows such as:

```
timestamp  name  price  profit
           bob     5      4
           jim     3      2
           jim     2      6 
           bob     6      7
           jim     4      1
           jim     6      3
           bob     3      1
```

The data base is sorted by a timestamp. I would like to be able to add a new column where it would take the last 2 values in the price column before the current value and average them into a new column. So that the first three rows would look something like this with a new column:

```
timestamp  name  price  profit  new column
           bob     5       4      4.5 
           jim     3       2       3
           jim     2       6       5

(6+3)/2 = 4.5   
(2+4)/2 = 3  
(4+6)/2 = 5
```

This isn't for a school project or anything this is just something I'm working on on my own. I've tried asking a similar question to this but I don't think I was very clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, I don't really understand where that last two numbers are coming from. Where is 6 +3 coming from?

Comment: That would be the average of the last two bob values and then the 2 + 4 would be the last two jim values.

Comment: Do you want "the last 2 values in the price column before the current value" or "the next 2 values in the price column after the current value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def shift_n_roll(df):
    return df.shift(-1).rolling(2).mean().shift(-1)

df['new column'] = df.groupby('name').price.apply(shift_n_roll)

df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I have one question though I am going to do this with a large number of samples as well, say 30, and when I do that I'm going to have 29 that will fill with NaN. I could use random numbers or regression to fill in the numbers but I'm wondering if you know an easy work around so that when it runs out of numbers it averages the last 29 and then 28 and so on until it gets to the end.

Comment: @jrich I would suggest selecting an answer to this question and then asking another question.  That way you'll have an opportunity to better express what you mean.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the result you want, I'm guess you want average of the two prices following the current one instead of "2 values in the price column before the current value".

I made up `timestamp` values that you omitted to be clear.

```
print df
   timestamp name  price  profit
0 2016-01-01  bob      5       4
1 2016-01-02  jim      3       2
2 2016-01-03  jim      2       6
3 2016-01-04  bob      6       7
4 2016-01-05  jim      4       1
5 2016-01-06  jim      6       3
6 2016-01-07  bob      3       1

#No need to sort if you already did.
#df.sort_values(['name','timestamp'], inplace=True)
df['new column'] = (df.groupby('name')['price'].shift(-1) + df.groupby('name')['price'].shift(-2)) / 2
print df.dropna()

   timestamp name  price  profit  new column
0 2016-01-01  bob      5       4         4.5
1 2016-01-02  jim      3       2         3.0
2 2016-01-03  jim      2       6         5.0
```